# How to determine if screen is enabled on android in C?

Tags: android, c, get, screen, state

I am developing a daemon in C for Android that needs to get display state of a device to work correctly.
I tried getting it through shell command with PIPE functionality:

```
char state[8];
FILE *pipe = popen("dumpsys locationpolicy | /sbin/busybox grep mScreenOn", "re");
fscanf(pipe, "mScreenOn=%s", state);
pclose(pipe);
return (!strcmp(state, "true"));
```

**dumpsys locationpolicy** is the only service query that works for my device and provides a screen state correctly (all other variants do not contain any information about screen), but on each attempt after the first 'state' contains corrupted data (first may contain "true" or "false", others look so: "@B"), though this command works perfectly when I try it from adb shell or directly from terminal emulator. Maybe it is because my program uses pthread multithreading, but it is important and I can't get rid of it.

Is there a way to get screen state directly by Linux-way, or is it impossible?

P.S.: Even when I try to call the query to Android and redirect it to file (through `system()`) to then read it directly from code, it then even does not create any file i write in my shell code... Example:

```
FILE *f;
char state[8];
system("dumpsys locationpolicy | /sbin/busybox grep mScreenOn >/tmp/.screen_state");
f = fopen("/tmp/.screen_state", "r");
fscanf(f, "mScreenOn=%s\n", state);
fclose(f);
return(!strcmp(state, "true"));
```